# Vim conversion error on EUR-sign € and dash-sign - when saving the file

Tags: macos, vim, encoding, file-conversion

In (mac)vim I use the following .vimrc

```
set guifont=Meslo_LG_M_Regular_for_Powerline:h12
set encoding=utf-8
```

When I write a € sign in the buffer and try to save it, I always get an error

```
CONVERSION ERROR in line xxxx
```

This appears as well on some type of dashes. As workaround I have to replace the signs, e.g. € -> EUR and than it will work fine to save the file. But this is annoying.

How can I get vim to write the € so that I can save the file without error messages?

Thats what I use:

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 21 2014 14:54:22) MacOS X (unix) version
ProductName:     Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.6
BuildVersion:   15G1510

Comment: What is file encoding? `set fileencoding?`

Answer (score 2):

With your `'encoding'` setting, Vim is able to represent the € sign internally. Buffers loaded into Vim for editing still have a particular `'fileencoding'`. If that one cannot represent the character (e.g. if it is `latin1`), you'll get the conversion error.

A quick fix is to force saving in UTF-8, e.g. via `:w ++enc=utf-8`.

Better adapt the global `'fileencodings'` setting so the the file gets detected right from the start. Note: `'fileencodings'` is the global option controlling the detection, `'fileencoding'` is the actual, buffer-local encoding used.